# Persisting Entity in EntityFramework 4.3.1 doesn't return navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework-4, savechanges, navigation-properties

I am working with the EntityFramework 4.3.1 in Visual Studio 2010.

I have a root entity object called **container** which has a navigation property called **containerversions** hanging off of it.

When a new containerversion is required I:

1. New up a **containerversion** object
2. Get the root container through the EF context
3. Add the new containerversion to the containerversions list property.
4. Save the context via Context.SaveChanges()

All of which works fine.

However, after the save when I look at the container object and inspect the containerversions collection property, the new containerversion is there, but it's navigation properties are not populated and it's type is not a System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxy but the newed up type of the object I created to add to the collection before saving.

Is there something I am missing when I am saving the rootentity that will cause the newly inserted containerversion navigation properties to be populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created the entity just by calling `new ContenerVersion` you will never get dynamic proxy for that instance. To get dynamic proxy you must use `objectContext.CreateObject` or `dbContext.ContainerVersions.Create`

Comment: That's what I'm talking about! Thank you very much that was exactly my problem =)